# Is there a cleaner/better way to run this code that shows the print number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is supposed to show what number corresponds to the print output every time the loop is ran. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

```
counter = 1
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(f"{counter} Hello World!")
    counter += 1
    i += 1
```

output:

```
1 Hello World!
2 Hello World!
3 Hello World!
4 Hello World!
5 Hello World!
```

Comment: Why are you bothering to maintain two separate, but nearly identical, variables `i` and `counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `counter = i + 1`, one option would be to just do `print(f"{i+1} Hello World!")` and get rid of `counter`.

I don't see what else you could mean by "better/cleaner way", if this isn't what you had in mind please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) iterator or `enumerate()` an existing one!

```py
>>> for counter in range(1, 5+1):
...     print("{} Hello World!".format(counter))
...
1 Hello World!
2 Hello World!
3 Hello World!
4 Hello World!
5 Hello World!
```

`range()` allows setting the start value, so beginning it at `1` saves you from doing further math on your counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(5):
    print(f"{i+1} Hello World!")
```

You can use the above code.